# reasoning: Can't modify non-lvalue subroutine

Tags: perl

This code does work. But my question is this:  If I uncomment the two commented lines and comment out the next three lines, I would get a `Can't modify non-lvalue subroutine` and I would like to know why?  I would save a variable and ride a ..., if I could use the commented lines.

Next question how would I make this more object oriented?

```
open FILE, "FBIDs" or die $!;
while (<FILE>) {
     @csv = split /,/; 
}
for (my $i=0;$i<$#csv;$i++) {
     my $browser = LWP::UserAgent->new( );
     my $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/$csv[$i]?fields=id,name\n";
     my $response = $browser->get($url);
#     $response->content=~s/[{}\"]//g;
#     my @json = split (/[,:]/,$response->content);
     my $resp=$response->content;
     $resp=~s/[{}\"]//g;
     my @json = split (/[,:]/,$resp);
     print $json[1],", ",$json[3],"\n";
     $browser->delete( );
}
close FILE;
```

Answer (score 5):

Perl realizes you're trying to do something useless — modifying a value that's not stored anywhere — so it throws an error. Remember that `$response->content` is a method call (something that returns a value), not variable (storage aka lvalue).

Answer (score 3):

`$response->content` or `$response->content()` is method call and you can't make substitution or change it.

On the other hand some perl functions can be treated in such way, and they are called [lvalue subroutines](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Lvalue-subroutines).